# Timeout for SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, sqldatasource

I'm keeping alive a C# app in VS 2010 that I inherited, and I'm stuck with a timeout issue.

A stored procedure is being called that is now taking much longer to execute is generating the following error:

> Could not retrieve record data: Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The `SqlDataSource` used is instantiated directly in code, and I don't know how to set the `CommandTimeout` property as it doesn't seem available. Is this true? If not how can I access that property?

The solutions I've seen have the `SqlDataSource` in the `.aspx` file and typically `CommandTimeout` is set in a control (ex: gridview) event. That's not the case here.

EDIT:

Some code

```
Results = new SqlDataSource();

Results.ConnectionString = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EM"].ConnectionString;

Results.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.Text;

Results.SelectCommand = "exec sproc";

DataView ReturnedDataSet = (DataView)Results.Select(new 
System.Web.UI.DataSourceSelectArguments());
```

Thanks.

Comment: Increase the value of Connection Timeout in your connection string. It should be in config file.

Comment: Code sets the stored procedure in SelectCommand property, and then calls  SqlDataSource.Select().

Comment: @user1080381 Sorry I misread your suggestion, I will try that.

Comment: Some code on the database call with it's parameters and command would be helpful.

Comment: Why are you creating a SqlDataSource directly in code? Why aren't you using a SqlConnection and SqlCommand? To me, that's the far more pressing matter - a SqlDataSource is meant to be declared in ASPX markup and used there. It doesn't belong directly in C#. I know from experience. I used to use SqlDataSource everywhere and it was a giant pain.

Comment: @mason Agreed, I inherited this code and I would not have done it that way. I've added the pertinent code per Jimenemex.

Comment: Setting the timeout in the connection string is probably not a good idea either - this will increase it everywhere that connection string is used. And you probably don't need to increase the timeout everywhere.

Comment: If you execute procedure alone how long does it take? Maybe the reason is in your procedure.

Comment: I have been working to modify the stored proc also. It is pulling data from different sql servers, it must aggregate data from tables with 30+ million rows and as it is written now it is taking over a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I strongly advise you to move (run!) away from SqlDataSource, you can set the command timeout from C#. There's an event that you can wire up an event handler to, this exposes the [DbCommand where you can set the timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dbcommand.commandtimeout).

```
var ds = new SqlDataSource("connectionString", "select * from dbo.Project_Master");
ds.Selecting += (object s, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e) => e.Command.CommandTimeout = 1000;
var dataView = (DataView)ds.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
```